# Date constructor doesn't like undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

So I've got some code:

```js
const embed = {}; // This is actually DiscordJS

if (year >= 1000 && year !== undefined && month >= 0 && month !== undefined && day >= 0 && day !== undefined && hour >= 0 && hour !== undefined && minute >= 0 && minute !== undefined && second >= 0 && second !== undefined) {
  if (year !== undefined && month !== undefined && day !== undefined && hour !== undefined && minute !== undefined && second !== undefined) {
    embed.setTimestamp(new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second));
  } else if (year !== undefined && month !== undefined && day !== undefined && hour !== undefined && minute !== undefined && second == undefined) {
    embed.setTimestamp(new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute));
  } else if (year !== undefined && month !== undefined && day !== undefined && hour !== undefined && minute == undefined && second == undefined) {
    embed.setTimestamp(new Date(year, month, day, hour));
  } else if (year !== undefined && month !== undefined && day !== undefined && hour == undefined && minute == undefined && second == undefined) {
    embed.setTimestamp(new Date(year, month, day));
  } else if (year !== undefined && month !== undefined && day == undefined && hour == undefined && minute == undefined && second == undefined) {
    embed.setTimestamp(new Date(year, month));
  } else if (year !== undefined && month == undefined && day == undefined && hour == undefined && minute == undefined && second == undefined) {
    embed.setTimestamp(new Date(year));
  }
}
```

Now, this is clearly spaghetti and annoying to maintain, and I'm pretty sure there is a much, **much** better way of doing it, now the problem is;

- Theoretically, I should be able to pass `new Date(20, undefined, undefined, undefined)`, however Date doesn't like that.
- I could create my own date-maker, but I'm trying to minimize the code as much as possible.

What is (if there is one) the correct way to create a Date with `undefined`? Thanks in advance! <3

Comment: [No, you shouldn't be able to pass `new Date(20, undefined, undefined, undefined)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#Syntax) the year and month are mandatory.

Comment: What even is the end goal here? I don't understand why all the `if/else` cases. Shouldn't `new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second)` be enough? If you pass `undefined` as a parameter, it's the same as not passing it. The only thing you have to ensure is that you either pass *zero* arguments or *at least two*.

Comment: OK, I tried this and `undefined` *is* treated as an actual argument to the constructor, it's not ignored. That's slightly unexpected.

Comment: The code looks strange. You have a wrapping condition that checks if **everything** is actually defined. Why do you even need nested ifs? `year >= 1000 && year !== undefined && month >= 0 && month !== undefined && day >= 0 && day !== undefined && hour >= 0 && hour !== undefined && minute >= 0 && minute !== undefined && second >= 0 && second !== undefined`

Comment: @VLAZ I've got an interface for people to enter each, if I do that, people might only want the minute, they have the ability to not provide all input: Including the first 2

Comment: @RigidStudios then you should either a) assume a valid input for those argument (e.g., current year, current month, current day, etc) or b) don't use `Date`. What *should* happen if somebody supplies only the minutes or hours, for example?

Comment: @VLAZ If somebody only supplies the minutes or hours then year, month, day, hour should all be ignored (As in 1st, January 1970, hours:minutes)

Comment: @YuryTarabanko Didn't mean to include that in the snippet, I'm re-doing it without.

Comment: @RigidStudios then just have a default for all values but take the user supplied value if any.

Comment: You could do it by explicitly providing default values. Say using shiny new null coalescing operator `embed.setTimestamp(new Date(year ?? 1970, month ?? 0, day ?? 1, hour ?? 0, minute ?? 0, second ?? 0))`

Comment: Thanks guys! I've used: `new Date(year || 1970, month || 0, day || 0, hour || null, minute || null, second || null)` and it works.

Comment: Don't forget milliseconds. The number of arguments matters.

Answer (score 1):

You might use a loop over an array, and spread syntax to call the `new Date` constructor:

```
const args = [year, month, day, hour, minute, second];
while (args[args.length-1] === undefined) args.length--;
embed.setTimestamp(new Date(...args));
```

Comment: If all values are undefined, the *while* loop throws a range error.